# Content Performance

Tags: terminology

What is a right word to describe the heading **Content/Performance?** It is about best and effective content that form a complete artefact.

The example of **heading** and paragraph as below:

> **5.4.1 Content/Performance** This is about a better user experience, the 
>   effectiveness of the artefact and the context of the contents. It
>   is part of the critical component for target users to experience, and
>   the aesthetic is explained in the post-question survey.

Comment: Where did you find this text? I think we need a little more background to be able to answer this properly.

Comment: I've written the text myself.

Comment: I've read the text following the heading a couple of times and my head started spinning. What are you actually saying? Do you mean *content performance*, or do you mean *content to performance ratio*, or do you mean *content or performance*?

Answer (score 4):

"Content/Performance" is a ratio. The amount of Content vs. the Performance is measured as a useful metric. Search Google on the phrase "Content/Performance" for more.

[What’s Your Content Performance Ratio?](http://uk.blueglass.com/blog/content-auditing/)

```
For example, if you have:
750 (green and amber pages) / 1,000 (indexed pages)
= 0.75
Content Performance Ratio = 3:4 (or 75%)
```

See also:
[What’s Really Important For Technical SEO](http://outspokenmedia.com/internet-marketing-conferences/technical-seo/)
"... the ratio between total pages indexed and the total number of pages generating current organic traffic"

[How To Analyze Your Content Performance In Google Analytics](http://searchengineland.com/how-to-analyze-your-content-performance-in-google-analytics-101455)
[Online Marketing...](http://www.businessframe.com/online-marketing-synopsis-v19/)

As the above shows, we may not be able to find a one-word substitution for the concept. Instead, we could say "*Content Performance **Ratio***" or "*Content Performance **Index***".